# How to process huge amount of data?

Tags: java, perl, shell, oracle11g, ibatis

***Database used :*** Oracle 11g

***Operating System :*** Red hat linux

**Technology used :** Java & Ibatis

**Description :**

- Have 2 tables (tableA and table B).
- TableA has more than 100000 records(12- 15 columns).
- TableB has more than 1000000 record(40 -45 columns).
- Need to check column1, column2, column3 and column4 values in tableA with column1 in tableB.
- If its available in tableB  then i need to update other columns in tableA.

How to do this?

**Issue :**

Currently we have done this using java/Ibatis. Frequently we are facing java heap space problems, since its included in, crontab for every 30min it will process the data and makes the environment slower.

Current Approach:

- from table A - reference no, user name, age and status where fetched using below query
  select referenceno, name, age, status from tableA where status = 'FAILED'.
  its almost returning 20lac rows and the same is stored in arraylist.
- from the arraylist, each row is compared with referenceno, name, age in table as  below
  select count(*) from tableB where referenveno= tableA.referenceno and name =tableA.name and age =tableA.age and deleteflag = 'N'.(as mentioned above tableB has almost 40lac records).
- If above query returns 1 then, it will update tableA with status as PASSED,

  if returns( <1) it will update tableA with status as FAILED and remarks as no matching found.

  if returns ( >1) it will update tableA with Status as FAILED and remarks as 'more than one matching is found'.

*Hope using shell script / perl can do the job? Please suggest the best way to do this!!!*

Comment: Which part of your description are you stuck with?

Comment: UPDATED question now with more inputs, Hope you will get the context now!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to write PL/SQL stored procedure which should be fastest way - Oracle database do not need to send data to java application then.

You may schedule such PL/SQL procedure thru oracle job mechanism.